# How to bring the zoom selector to the front of the chart with chartjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have a chart made with chartjs in which I calculate the area between two lines. Now I want to use a selector to zoom in on this graph. However, the selector is behind the chart area. I want to know how to place this selector over the chart.

It is currently like this

[image: It is currently like this]

The code that builds the graph is this:

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'linha 1',            
            data:[
              {x: -11, y: 7},
              {x: -11, y: 7},
              {x: 3, y: 8},
            ],
            fill: '+1',
            showLine: true,
            borderColor: '#009999',
            backgroundColor: '#009999',
          }, 
          {
            label: 'linha 2',
            data: [
              {x: 0, y: 7},
              {x: 0, y: 7},
              {x: 8, y: 8},
            ],
            borderColor: '#f00',
            showLine: true,
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
          }
        ]
        },
        options: {         
          plugins: {
            zoom: {
              zoom: {
                mode: 'xy',
                drag: {
                  enabled: true,
                  borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)'
                }
              }
              
            },
          },
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve], so the actual DOM it generates could be inspected? Currently, we have no way of knowing versions of Chart.js and Vue.js used, wether or not you're using a dedicated `vue-chart-js` type plugin, etc...

Comment: It's not possible at the moment. There is a issue and a PR pending in the project to address that issue. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/pull/680